# PHP function to compare now time to time in database

Tags: php, mysql, time

I am trying to show different content based on the time recorded in my database.

From 1800 pm to 0800 am show content B. 
The rest of the remaining time show content A.

My database field is storing time field so in database 1800 pm is stored as 18:00:00 same goes to 0800 am, it is stored as 08:00:00.

Below is my logic to get content B when time is between 18:00:00 to 08:00:00:

```
$now = strtotime(date('H:i:s'));
$time_from = strtotime($data['date_from']); //18:00:00
$time_to = strtotime($data['date_to']); // 08:00:00
if($now >= $time_from && $now <= $time_to){
   echo 'content A';
}
```

The above code will only work if my `$time_to` is within 23:59:59 as `$now` will always be bigger than `08:00:00`. Lets say the time now is `23:30:00`, my codes will never echo "content A" out because `23:30:00` is bigger than `08:00:00`.

How can i make the logic work to check by time only then to display the content?

@All, im editing the code again. Yes. i did put $now = strtotime(date('H:i:s'));. But it is not working as well. Firstly, the current now unix timestamp will always be bigger than 08:00:00 unix timestamp. let's say the time now is 23:30:00. The unix timestamp will always be bigger than 08:00:00.

Comment: Why you don't use Carbon Library for manipulate date it is so easy https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (date("H:i") >= '08:00' && date("H:i") <= '18:00') {
    // Retrieve content 'A'
} else {
    // Retrieve content 'B'
}
```

Comment: 08:00:00 should be <= as i am looking to display content between 18:00:00 to 08:00:00. The logic should go backwards. it should be from 18:00:00pm till 08:00:00 am

Comment: This way will work @Kimberlee - it's just different logic to how you've been attempting it.  Work out when to show content A and at other times show content B.

Comment: yes.  It works. i didnt think that reverse logic would work in my case. I've make changes to my codes and the logic. Thanks Danmullen!

Answer (score 1):

before making the comparision, you need to [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) your `$now` variable as well, try:

```
$now = date('H:i:s');
$time_from = strtotime($data['date_from']); //18:00:00
$time_to = strtotime($data['date_to']); // 08:00:00
$now_str = strtotime($now);
if($now_str >= $time_from && $now_str <= $time_to){
   echo 'content A';
}
```

Comment: i did add in strtotime to my $now. I've missed out that part in my question. Therefore i've edited it. Even with strtotime, it does not help to resolve the problem. let's say the time now is 23:30:00. The unix timestamp will always be bigger than 08:00:00.